# error: lvalue required

Tags: lvalue

```
// getline : empty string array and max length as input
// stores input stream to array and return its length

#include<stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 100
int getline1(char* , int );
int main(){
    char *s;
    int i;
    s=(char*)malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(char));
    i=getline1(s,LENGTH);
    printf("%s %d",s,i);
    return 0;
}

int getline1(char *s, int lim){

    int c ,i;
    i = 0;
    printf("%u",s);
    while(--lim >= 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c = '\n'){
        *(s+i)=c; //error : lvalue required
        i++;
    }
    if(c=='\n'){
        *(s+i)=c;
        i++;
    }
    *(s+i)='\0';
    return i;
}
```

I get the error mentioned in the mentioned line can any body tell whats wrong. code works fine if i use arrays.getline : empty string array and max length as input
 stores input stream to array and return its length

Answer (score 0):

It cannot assign the value to the `*(s+i)` expression. Understandably so since you dereference it, leaving the value at that position (which is a constant).

Try using `s[i]` instead.

Comment: nope actually what i've done is correct. I was concentrating on the wrong line. the problem is in while "c='\n'" that should be c=='\n'.
thanx anyway.

Comment: i was about to answer my own question but can't ...i don't have reputation :((....